# Why does my code doesnt work when connecting with server in a function but works okay when I called the connection using __init__?

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

I am trying to establish a connection with a server with a button instead of trying it when the application starts. I tried initializing the client class in "MySocket" in the "TitleWindow" and it works fine but when I tried the same thing with a function call my "self.sock" in the function "get_data" and "send_data" turns into None

This code works fine.

```
class TitleWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TitleWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = 0
        self.send_text = 0
        try:
            self.sock = MySocket()
            Thread(target=self.send_data).start()
            Thread(target=self.get_data).start()
            self.manager.current = "main"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            print("No Connection to server")
            self.manager.current = "connect"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    def get_data(self):
        while True:
                self.text = self.sock.get_data()
                print(self.text.decode('utf-8'))
                return self.text


    def send_data(self, msg=None):
        while True:
                # msg = input()
                self.sock.send_data(msg)
                break
```

But this does not?

```
class TitleWindow(Screen):  # connection to server may start here
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TitleWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sock = None
        self.text = 0
        self.send_text = 0

    def next_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = "main"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "up"

    def connection(self):
        try:
            self.sock = MySocket()
            print(self.sock)
            Thread(target=self.send_data).start()
            Thread(target=self.get_data).start()
            self.manager.current = "main"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            sleep(0.1)
            self.manager.current = "connect"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    def get_data(self):
        while True:
                self.text = self.sock.get_data()
                print(self.text.decode('utf-8'))
                return self.text
          

    def send_data(self, msg=None):
        while True:
                # msg = input()
                self.sock.send_data(msg)
                break
```

This is the client program where i establish the socket(client.py)

```
class MySocket:

    #def __init__(self, host="133.54.230.187", port=8000):
    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=54545):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        print("Connected")


    def get_data(self):
        recv_msg = self.sock.recv(1024)
        return recv_msg

    def send_data(self, send_msg):
        self.sock.send(send_msg.encode())
```

my.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    TitleWindow:
    ConnectionWindow:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name : "main"
    FloatLayout:
    Button :
            pos_hint : {"x":0.45,"y":0.3}
            text : "Start"
            on_release :
                root.data_call()




<TitleWindow>:
    name : "title"
    Label :
        id:title_label
        text : "WELCOME!"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.5}




    Button :
        text : "Proceed"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.25}
        on_release :
            root.connection()

<ConnectionWindow>
    name : "connect"
    Label :
        id:connect_label
        text : "Server is not available, please reconfigure the device..."
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y" : 0.5}
    Button :
        id : return
        text : "Return"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.25 , "center_y" : 0.25}
        disabled : False
        on_release :
            root.top()
    Button :
        id : recon_button
        text : "Proceed"
        pos_hint : {"center_x" : 0.75 , "center_y" : 0.25}
        disabled : False
        on_release :
            root.reconnect()
```

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
import socket
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from client import *
from threading import Thread

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TitleWindow(Screen):  # connection to server may start here
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TitleWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sock = None
        self.text = 0
        self.send_text = 0

    def next_screen(self):
        self.manager.current = "main"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "up"

    def connection(self):
        try:
            self.sock = MySocket()
            print(self.sock)
            Thread(target=self.send_data).start()
            Thread(target=self.get_data).start()
            self.manager.current = "main"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            sleep(0.1)
            self.manager.current = "connect"
            self.manager.transition.direction = "left"

    def get_data(self):
        while True:
                self.text = self.sock.get_data()
                print(self.text.decode('utf-8'))
                return self.text
          

    def send_data(self, msg=None):
        while True:
                # msg = input()
                self.sock.send_data(msg)
                break

control = TitleWindow()

class ConnectionWindow(Screen):  # establish connection Here if not then have a button to retry

    def reconnect(self):
        try:
            control.connection()
        except WindowsError:
            print("No Connection")

    def top(self):
        self.manager.current = "title"
        self.manager.transition.direction = "up"

    pass
class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.seat = 0

    def data_call(self):
        control.send_data = 2 
        control.send_data(str(self.seat))   #Error Occured Here     




class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        if platform == 'android' or platform == 'ios':
            Window.maximize()
        else:
            Window.size = (620, 1024)
        return WindowManager()


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMainApp().run()
```

This is the error that I got when trying to call the "data_call" function from the MainWindow class.

```
self.sock.send_data(msg)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_data'
```

Comment: Can you add the error you got?

Comment: I added the error code that I got after removing the ExceptionHandling.

Comment: You moved the code to `connection` but you don't call `connection` in your second example.

Comment: I called the connection function in another class and it connected fine but when i tried to call the get_data and send_data function it said that my self.sock is now is a NoneType

Comment: So this code can't run as it is, but you don't show how this is really used and we have to guess the problem? I'm out.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for my ignorance, it is my first time posting problem here. I have edited the question. If there are any lack of details in the questions I will provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your code:

```
control = TitleWindow()
```

which creates a new instance of `TitleWindow` (not the one that had its `connection()` method called). You need to use the correct instance of `TitleWindow` in your `MainWindow`. That can be done inside the `MainWindow` class using something like:

```
control = self.manager.get_screen('title')
```

Comment: I used control = TitleWindow() in order to call the "send_data" function from the TitleWindow class which I used in the MainWindow class.

Is the usage wrong in this case?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. Please read my answer.